# Accessing flask.g variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, flask

how can I access flask.g variable in javascript function. I am able to access this directly in HTML e.g {% if g.locale != 'en' %}

Comment: Javascript runs on the browser, not on the server. You cannot access `flask.g` on the browser. Include such data as needed in the page you send to the browser instead.

Comment: this probably isn't good practice. Does it need to be bound to `g`?

Comment: It is not, I understand it now, after reading Miguel's reply.thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access `flask.g` on the browser, unfortunately, that exists only on the server. The closest thing you can do is write the `g` attributes that you are interested in to the template as Javascript code. Example:

```
<script>
    var g_locale = "{{ g.locale }}";
    alert(g_locale);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Miguel, thanks for the reply.I am able to access the variable. but the local variable does not get the latest value of the global variable

Comment: There is no "latest value", by the time Javascript gets hold of this value `Flask.g` has ceased to exist, the `g` container is created and destroyed as part of each request. What you get is the value that was on `g` at the time the template was rendered.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, I understand it now. I was trying to access it after an ajax call from the template.

Comment: @Ryan: you can certainly return something from g in the response of the Ajax call, that works in the same way as my example above, only you would be returning it as part of a JSON or XML body.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var g_locale = {{ g.locale|tojson }};
    alert(g_locale);
</script>
```